# LookUpRows not populating

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to show the description based on the customer ID present in the 2nd DE.

I have created 2 DE's.

```
FirstDE(SendableDE): FirstName,LastName,Customerid
SecondDE: Customerid,Description,Region
```

The region has north and south values but want to populate only north records.

This is my Code

```ampscript
%%[

Var @Fname, @Lname, @ND
Set @Fname = [FirstName]
Set @Lname = [LastName]


Set @ND=LookUpRows("SecondDE","Region",North)

]%%
```

Based on your region : %%=v(@ND)=%% you will receive extra benefits

> Error: The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. Function Call: LookUpRows("SecondDE","Region",North) Attribute or Field Name: North

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is slightly off, you would want to do:

```ampscript
%%[

Set @Fname = AttributeValue("FirstName")
Set @Lname = AttributeValue("LastName")
set @customerid = AttributeValue("customerid")

Set @Region = LookUp("SecondDE","Region","CustomerID",@customerid)

IF @Region == "North" THEN

 /* Your extra benefits stuff */

ENDIF

]%%
```

You will want to match the customerid fields as the foreign keys to create the relationship between the two DEs and then from there you will get the correct Region via the Lookup.  You can then use that value to create an if statement to determine if they get the extra benefits or not.

Comment: May I know Why I can't use the LookUpRows function instead of lookup?? My idea is to get multiple rows from another DE

Comment: @Reva You certainly could if you wanted, in your example, you were just looking for the one value, which is why I used the Lookup instead of LookupRows